# set onLongClick for a gridview in Android

Tags: android, gridview, view, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I want to set `onLongClickListener` for a `gridview` and only want the `onLongClick()` method to be invoked when the user long presses on an empty space of the gridview. I am also using an `onItemLongClickListener` for the items of the gridView which works fine.

I have tried putting a `view` and the `gridview` within a `framelayout` with equal width and height(`view's` height is set programmatically to match that of the `gridview`) but the `onClick()` only works for the view which is on top(declared first in the frame layout).

Is there any way i can set `onLongClickListenter` for a `gridView`? I need both `onLongClick()` and `onItemLongClick()` to work.

Here is my `xml layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/taskBar" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <View 
                android:id="@+id/gridViewOnClickArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </View> 
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.example.androidfilemanager.DirectoryFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
            </fragment>


        </FrameLayout>
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/taskBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/taskbarLinearLayout"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dip"
                    android:text="@string/home"
                    android:background="@drawable/taskbar_item"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                <View 
                    android:layout_width="2.5dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#001d27"/>
            </LinearLayout>  
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's your problem, the two methods exist and are applicable for type GridView : you just have to do this :

Comment: setting onlongclick for the gridview deosnt work; have already tried it.

Comment: You mean that you tried something like that :
GridView test = new GridView(this);
test.setOnLongClickListener(l);
test.setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);

Comment: yes..dont think gridview is supposed to have a onLongClick() but i still want one.

Comment: I think that it can have one but Android cannot distinguish the difference between the two long clicks.

Comment: there has to be a way to use both instead of having to choose between the two.